# Incorrect syntax near ')' in hibernate named query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hql, named-query

I am facing an error mentioned above, while fetching a list of values in a named query.

Here is the HQL syntax for this:

```
select rolepermis0_.permission_name as col_0_0_ from role_permission rolepermis0_ where rolepermis0_.role_id in ()
```

and here is the named query syntax i am using:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "rolePermission.getPermissionsByRoleIds",
    //query = "SELECT NEW com.bitwise.tdm.project.internal.entity.Project(p.projectId, p.projectName,p.projectDescription) FROM UserProjectEntity up LEFT JOIN up.user u LEFT JOIN  up.project p WHERE up.userId = :userId")
    query = "SELECT rp.permissionName FROM RolePermissionEntity rp WHERE rp.roleId IN (:roleIds)")
```

Can someone please point out what am i missing in this?

Comment: What about removing both parenthesis, so that the HQL remains `SELECT rp.permissionName FROM RolePermissionEntity rp WHERE rp.roleId IN :roleIds`?

Comment: trying that for now

Comment: Tried. Didn't work.. actually is there any dialect related problem?

Comment: Found it. Actually in IN clause , the list was coming as empty, so it threw a SQLGrammerexception for the same. The setParameter method didn't handle empty or null values.